# How can I determine the version number of a given Kernel driver?

Tags: kernel

Is there a way to reliably list a version number (or publishing party or bug report address) for a given Kernel driver?

Here's what I tried instead, which did not work super well, for a given driver:

```
# lsusb | grep 232
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 0557:2008
ATEN International Co., Ltd UC-232A Serial Port [pl2303]

# lsmod | grep pl2303
pl2303 19133
# locate pl2303
/boot/grub/i386-pc/usbserial_pl2303.mod
/lib/modules/3.13.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-88-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.ko

# strings -n 45 pl2303.ko
description=Prolific PL2303 USB to serial adaptor driver

# websearch "Prolific PL2303 USB to serial adaptor driver"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that modinfo is the command you want, in your example:

```
modinfo pl2303
```

In the output, there *should* be a line starting "version"